# PDFkit open PDF print dialog

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pdf, printing, pdfkit

I'm using PDFKit in rails. I'm creating an application that allows a user to view a pdf in a tab (onclick of a button). I would like the print dialog to automatically be opened up.

I tried to call `window.print()`, but that seems to want to print the page as if it's HTML. I want to open up the PDF print dialog (as if you are clicking the print button in the tools area in the bottom left of the PDF, where you can zoom in and out, etc.)

Here is my initializer:

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = `which wkhtmltopdf`.to_s.strip
  config.default_options = {
      :encoding=>"UTF-8",
      :page_width => '2.125in',
      :page_height => '1in',
      :margin_top=>"0in",
      :margin_right=>"0in",
      :margin_bottom=>"0in",
      :margin_left=>"0in",
  :print_media_type => true
  }
end
```

## This is the PDF:

[image: This is the PDF]

## This is what happens when I hit <kbd>ctrl+P</kbd>:

[image: This is how I would like the print dialog]

## This is what it looks like when I run window.print() in the console:

[image: This is what it looks like with window.print]

I want the print dialog to open in the way that it does when I press <kbd>ctrl+P</kbd>, since that prints to a page the size of the PDF.

**How do I open the print dialog the same way <kbd>ctrl+P</kbd> does, using JavaScript, when displaying a PDF?**